# Convert hex string to little endian

Tags: python, c++, endianness

I would like to convert string representation of hex for example:

```
"18ec1975b97174"
```

to little endian string.
I'm familiar with python so I can achieve that with

```
struct.pack("<L", "18ec1975b97174")
```

What will be equivalent in C++? It is possible to work on string or should I convert that to numeric value first?

Comment: Your question a bit unclear. String is just sequence of bytes, and "byte order" term not applicable. You want to convert number, that represents as string? There are no standart C++ instrument to work with numbers greater than 64 bit width. You can do it manually.

Comment: `struct.pack("<L", "18ec1975b97174")` gave me an error: `struct.error: required argument is not an integer`

Comment: Please say what is the expected result. Or at least give a correct Python equivalent! C can easily do what you want, but currently I cannot guess what you want...

Comment: Your python example won't work. I think you mean `struct.pack("<L", 0x18ec1975b97174)`? perhaps? Oh, actually I don't think you mean that either. I think you want to reverse the order of the "bytes" represented by the text? Either way, your Python version won't work the way you think it will.

Comment: I think, in python, what you mean is something like: `"".join(reversed([x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2)]))` where x was your input string? (This code doesn't work if the input string isn't an even number of characters long, but I'm just trying to illustrate a method). I mean, I suspect you could just transliterate that to C++ (using a for loop with a += 2 incrementer and a buffer to write the result into, but i don't know C++ enough to answer...)

Comment: Your python example is wrong, it should be `"18ec1975b97174".decode('hex')[::-1].encode('hex')`

Comment: They probably meant struct.unpack("<I", struct.pack(">I", i))[0]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a machine that uses little endian, in C++ you can use the [NTOH functions](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html).

These will convert numbers in network order (big endian) to host order (litle endian).

This will only work on numeric values though.